# Retrieving videos uploaded from iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an app that fetches photos and videos from the library.

I am using ALAssetsLibrary to fetch the contents from the library. But I can't retrieve the videos album from the library using this.

I am using the following code to retrieve the contents:

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if (group || group.numberOfAssets >= 1)
     {

         [tmpAssets addObject:group];

     }else{

         self.assetAlbums = tmpAssets;

         *stop = YES;

         if(self.assetAlbums.count){

             //parse contents and reload view
         }

     }
 }
failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     //failed

 }];
```

I am getting all other pictures and videos.

I have used a workaround of creating one videos album and filling its contents with the results from the `ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock` with `allVideos` filter.

but the ones that I upload from iTunes (those that get into the videos folder in the library) are not getting retrieved.